# underline <a> and <span> like a whole link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am trying to  underline with one line the `<a>` and the `<span>`

I want it all to be a link with an underline.  It leaves a small space between the word and the span, but it shouldn't.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<a  href="#" role="button">
    Saber mais   
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right size"></span>  
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right size segundoGlyph "></span>
    </a>
```

Edit 1: And when the text size is higher than the glyphicon? the icon has a thin line and the text a heavy line!

Comment: Exactly. Hence do not change to v4

Comment: @mplungjan they removed icons :) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/icons/

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components in FA use fas fa-chevron-right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may add it on hover, but you need to pay attention as there is `top:1px` set to the icons by default so you need to remove it to have a full continuous line:

```css
a.good .glyphicon {
  top: 0;
}

a:hover .glyphicon {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="#" role="button" class="good">
Good one   
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right size"></span>  
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right size segundoGlyph "></span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="#" role="button">
Bad one   
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right size"></span>  
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right size segundoGlyph "></span>
</a>
```

Another solution is to make them `inline` as by default they are `inline-block` and if you refer to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props):

> Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and
>   absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic
>   inline-level descendants such as **inline blocks** and inline tables.

```css
a .glyphicon {
  top: 0;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="#" role="button">
Saber mais   
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right size"></span>  
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right size segundoGlyph "></span>
</a>
```

---

And to explain the small line you see between the two icons initially:

> Underlines, overlines, and line-throughs are applied only to text
>   (including **white space**, letter spacing, and word spacing): margins,
>   borders, and padding are skipped

So if you remove any white space you will see the line under the text only:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="#" role="button">
Good one<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right size"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right size segundoGlyph "></span></a>
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed in the comment, different `font-size` between the text and the icon will make the underline different, so we may rely on border in this case:

```css
a:hover {
 text-decoration:none!important;
 border-bottom:1px solid
}
.glyphicon {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a href="#" role="button">
Good one<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right size"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right size segundoGlyph "></span></a>
```

Comment: what if the font-size of text is higher than the font-size of the glyphicon? t shows a heavy line in the text and a thin line with the glyphicon! How can you solve that?